# Is there such a thing as a ranged unarmed attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, ranged-attack, unarmed-combat, dnd-4e-character-builder

So I haven't had much time to create a character for playing D&D and thought I'd try my luck using a character generator for 4e, so I had something to tinker with before game. Mind you I am a pretty unseasoned player, so I'm still learning much about the game.

I wanted a Tiefling Bard with Virtue of Valor at Level 7. The generator gave me At Will powers as well, and for some reason I got Jinx Shot as one of the attacks. The weird thing is that this bard only had a long sword and a light shield as weapons, and for some reason the only "ranged" weapon I had was listed as Unarmed (Ranged) 1D4 to AC.

I'm inexperienced so I didn't think much of it and just thought Jinx Shot was a spell being shot out of my bardic hands. My GM was baffled though, as he understood it as Jinx Shot needs a ranged weapon to work, and he had never heard of ranged unarmed weaponry before.

My question is this, is there even such a thing as ranged unarmed? Did I just stumble on a weird configuration using the generator? A breakthrough of how and why I can/can't use Jinx Shot would be appreciated, so I can gain a better understanding.

I'm sorry if what I've told so far is too vague, I wouldn't mind editing in extra info if needed.

Comment: Why 4e though? You should convince your dm to switch to 5e. Or at least 3.5e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your character can't make use of this spell unarmed

Sadly I think you've found an issue with the generator.
According to a [4e wiki](http://dnd4.wikia.com). [Jinx Shot](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Jinx_shot) has the [**weapon** keyword](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_(keyword)). The rules pertaining to that say

> The weapon keyword on a power indicates that a weapon or unarmed attacking must be wielded to use the power. The power's range is equal to the reach or range of the weapon being wielded.

Because you have no ranged weapon, you have no range for the power to use either. Because of this, you cannot use use Jinx Shot unarmed unless you find some other rule, ability, or spell that grants you a ranged unarmed attack.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go with "Yes, but not on your build." Odds are it was just a screw up in the character generator, because the way you get it is fairly specific.

Step 1: Be a monk. You need access to the Monk Unarmed Combat feature, either through being a monk or the Master of the Fist multiclass feat. This makes your unarmed strike an one-handed off-hand weapon
Step 2: Be a barbarian. Works pure, hybrid, or multiclass. This qualifies you for the Hurl Weapon feat, which allows you to use a one-handed off-hand weapon as a Heavy Thrown weapon. Guess what Step 1 made a one-handed off-hand weapon?

So yes, you can make unarmed strike into a ranged weapon, and can potentially do so on a bard if you generator gave you 13 Strength, 13 Dex, Master of the Fist, MC Barbarian, and Hurl Weapon. But if it did, you need to get a new generator, because that thing is trying to get you killed.

Comment: That's actually quite hilarious. Thanks for outlining one outlandish but pretty cool possibility. So basically a monk barbarian can throw his fists so to speak. That's very cool indeed. Do you know if a Monk Barbarian variant of this type is worth trying out?

Comment: The friend of mine who showed it to me was playing a Ranger|Barbarian hybrid who multiclassed monk and used the Avalanche Hurler paragon path, because it let him get a +3 proficiency 1d10 damage one handed weapon that he was dual wielding because fists. Characetr sheet (with permission): https://www.myth-weavers.com/sheet.html#id=285033

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing from the builder are the stats for an Improvised ranged weapon, e.g. if you picked up a chair or a rock and threw it, it would have Range 5/10 and do 1d4 damage. This idea is not at all recommended, as you will have to spend a minor action every turn picking up a rock or something, you won't get any proficiency or enhancement bonuses to attack or damage, and you will, in general, be sad.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] to learn more about the site. This answer may benefit from including a small quote and/or reference where one may find this rule for Improvised ranged weapons. Thank you for contributing and happy gaming!